# How to make the JDialog invisible when the JProgressBar reaches 100%?

Tags: java, swing, jdialog, jprogressbar

Relevant piece of code:

```
JProgressBar progress;
JButton button;     
JDialog dialog;      //Fields of my GUI class

progress=new JProgressBar(JProgressBar.HORIZONTAL,0,100);
button=new JButton("Done");
dialog=new JDialog();             //Done from methods

progress.setValue(0);
progress.setStringPainted(true);
progress.setBorderPainted(true);  //Also done from methods

button.addActionListener(this);   //Also done from methods

dialog.setLayout(new FlowLayout(FlowLayout.CENTER));
dialog.setTitle("Please wait...");
dialog.setBounds(475,150,250,100);
dialog.setModal(true);            //Also done from methods

dialog.add(new JLabel("Loading..."));
dialog.add(progress);             //Also done from methods
```

And here is the `actionPerformed` method:

```
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
{
    dialog.setVisible(true);
    Task task=new Task();
    task.start();


    //After the JProgressBar reaches 100%, do the following things:
    /*progress.setValue(progress.getMinimum());
    dialog.setVisible(false);*/
}
```

`Task` is a nested class just below the `actionPerformed` method:

```
private class Task extends Thread {    
  public void run(){
     for(int i =0; i<= 100; i++){
        final int j = i;
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
           public void run() {
              progress.setValue(j);
           }
        });
        try {
           Thread.sleep(10);
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {}
     }
  }
}
```

I want the JDialog not to be visible when the JProgressBar in it reaches 100% . Currently, the JDialog does not close when the JProgressBar reaches 100%. Actually, I want to the commented piece of code in `actionPerformed` to be executed after the JProgressBar reaches 100%.

I've tried `task.join();` just after `task.start();`, but this gave a negative result. When I did this, the JDialog's border was displayed and then, after a moment, the dialog closes. I never see anything in the JDialog.

Note that I am new to `SwingUtilities`.

How do I make the program do what I am expecting?

Comment: Use a `SwingWorker`...okay, but once the `run` method reaches the end, you will need a reference to the `dialog` so you can call `dispose` on it...

Comment: @MadProgrammer , Thanks. `dialog` is visible in `Task`. So I can directly use it. But there is one small problem. See the comment under @Kuba's answer

Comment: Just because the dialog is visible, doesn't mean you can interact with it, you still need a reference to it of some kind. As to you "other" problem, consider using a SwingWorker instead

Comment: @MadProgrammer , Thanks. I finally got it working using `SwingWorker`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about:

```
public void run() {
          if(j == 100)
              dialog.dispose();
          else
              progress.setValue(j);
       }
```

Comment: This did the trick! Thanks! But there is one small problem. The JProgressBar dosen't move when I press the JButton. It stays at 0%. This happens sometimes only. Once this does not happen, then this problem never appears. Any idea what's causing this?