# Changing the default cursor to busy cursor does not work as expected

Tags: java, swing, cursor, swingworker, jprogressbar

After many attempts trying to make a `JProgressBar` work as expected, I finally became successful at achieving my goal. I had used [@MadProgrammer](https://stackoverflow.com/users/992484/madprogrammer)'s [advice](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29746517/how-to-make-the-jdialog-invisible-when-the-jprogressbar-reaches-100#comment47625299_29746517) and used a `SwingWorker` to finally get the program work as I want.

Now, I want the cursor to change into [image: BUSY_CURSOR]
 when my `JProgressBar` goes from 0% to 100%. I've googled and found out that

```
setCursor(Cursor.getPredefinedCursor(Cursor.WAIT_CURSOR));
```

is the code to do it. I've tried it but it does not work as expected.

Relevant piece of code:

```
JProgressBar progress;
JButton button;     
JDialog dialog;      //Fields of my GUI class

progress=new JProgressBar(JProgressBar.HORIZONTAL,0,100);
button=new JButton("Done");
dialog=new JDialog();             //Done from methods

progress.setValue(0);
progress.setStringPainted(true);
progress.setBorderPainted(true);  //Also done from methods

button.addActionListener(this);   //Also done from methods

dialog.setLayout(new FlowLayout(FlowLayout.CENTER));
dialog.setTitle("Please wait...");
dialog.setBounds(475,150,250,100);
dialog.setModal(true);            //Also done from methods

dialog.add(new JLabel("Loading..."));
dialog.add(progress);             //Also done from methods
```

And here is the `actionPerformed` method:

```
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
{
    setCursor(Cursor.getPredefinedCursor(Cursor.WAIT_CURSOR));

    Task task=new Task();
    task.addPropertyChangeListener(this);
    task.execute();
    dialog.setVisible(true);
}
```

The `propertyChange` method:

```
public void propertyChange(PropertyChangeEvent evt) {
    if("progress" == evt.getPropertyName()){
        int progressnum = (Integer) evt.getNewValue();
        progress.setValue(progressnum);
    }
}
```

and the nested class `Task`:

```
   class Task extends SwingWorker<Void, Void> {
        /*
         * Main task. Executed in background thread.
         */
        @Override
        public Void doInBackground() {
            int progressnum = 0;
            setProgress(0);

            while (progressnum < 100) {
                try {
                    Thread.sleep(10);
                } catch (InterruptedException ex) {
                    System.err.println("An error occured:"+ex);
                    ex.printStackTrace();
                }

                progressnum ++;
                setProgress(Math.min(progressnum, 100));
            }
            return null;
        }

        /*
         * Executed in event dispatching thread
         */
        @Override
        public void done() {
            //setCursor(null); //turn off the wait cursor
            setCursor(Cursor.getDefaultCursor()); //Is this one or the one above it right?
            dialog.dispose();
            progress.setValue(progress.getMinimum());
        }
    }
```

When I press `button`, the JDialog with the JProgressBar appears and the JProgressBar goes from 0% to 100%. During this time, the cursor needs to be changed into  [image: BUSY_CURSOR](busy cursor) and when the JProgressBar reaches 100%, the normal cursor([image: NORMAL_CURSOR]
) needs to be restored.

The problem is, when I press `button`, the cursor changes to the busy cursor for a split second and then, changes back into the original cursor. I want the cursor to be busy until the JProgressBar reaches 100%.

I've added the code to convert the cursor into a busy cursor in the `actionPerformed` method and the restore the normal cursor in the `done` method of the nested class `Task`. Note that I've also included the necessary packages.

- What is causing the problem?
- How do I fix it?
- Should I use

  ```
  setCursor(null);
  ```

  or

  ```
  setCursor(Cursor.getDefaultCursor());
  ```

  to restore the cursor?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you call `setCursor()` on the `JFrame`, it only has effect for the frame, not the dialog. Similarly, when you call `setCursor()` on the `JDialog`, it only has effect for the dialog, not the frame. There the problem: you did not set the cursor for the dialog, right?

I'm not sure whether `setCursor(null)` is safer than `setCursor(Cursor.getDefaultCursor())`. :p

Comment: Now I get it. This was exactly what I was looking for. I thought that `setCursor` sets the given cursor throughout the program. Why did my code work? Because the GUI class, `extends JFrame`. So, all this time I was setting the cursor to the JFrame? Arrgh! Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Kudos for creating a modeless dialog and using a worker thread, which will improve the user's experience with decreased perceived latency. Consider adding a [`MouseListener`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/events/mouselistener.html) to the dialog when the worker starts. Display the `WAIT_CURSOR` in your implementation of `mouseEntered()`, and restore the default in your implementation of `mouseExited()`. Remove the listener in `done()`. This will make the progress and cursor visual cues coincide when the user's attention shifts to the dialog *while* the worker is running.

Comment: When I do this, the cursor needs to be in JDialog in order for it to turn into a busy cursor, right?

Comment: Exactly. The advantage is that your remaining GUI remains responsive, while the user gets visual confirmation that the operation is still pending.

Comment: Ok . Your suggestion makes sense. Thanks